# smartgwt and regular expressions

Tags: regex, smartgwt

I am trying to use setKeyPressFilter method of TextItem to restrict the input to signed integers by using the argument "[+-]?[0-9]+". But the only characters that i can type are the digits, the signs do not appear.Is the regular expression wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the regex won't work is that it forces that there be at least one digit, so you wouldn't be able to type the sign digit.  If you are able to type the digit, then left arrow to the begining of the string, then type the sign digit, then you'll probably want to change the regex to `[-+]?\d*`

Otherwise, tt might be that are trying to apply the regex to the single character that is being typed (in `setKeyPressFilter`).  And of course this wouldn't work either for the same reason: you are forcing there to be a digit, so there is never room in that 1 keypress for both the digit and the sign.

Comment: Weird! Because it seems http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/regtest.htm?rp=%5B-%2B%5D%3F%5B0-9%5D%2B&rf=g&me=2&ts=this%20is%20text%20and%20costs%20--2345%20or%204232 that works the specific regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
+ and - are special character u cant use directly
```

remove single quotes inside double quote and use{ i cant type directly Here}

```
"'\'+'\'-"
```

[Basic syntax](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html)

Comment: i cannot understand what you say ... the setKeyPressFilter takes a String argument, the regular expression. So i have to define the regular expression as a String (that's why it is in ""). After all when you include characters in [] when writing regular expressions stop to be special!